# how to check a array of imgs is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got the code here
a array like this var pics = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3,jpg'];

loop throught the array

```
var j = 0; 
var(var i in pics){ 
$(document.createElement(img)).attr('src',pics[i]).load(function(){
    alert(pics[i]+'is loaded');
    j++;
})}

if(j == pics.length){
alert('fully loaded');}
```

but all i got is 3,jpg is loaded all the time,
how to solve this? where am i wrong?

Comment: Big dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857896/jquery-callback-after-all-images-in-dom-are-loaded
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488104/how-to-know-when-all-images-inside-a-specific-div-are-loaded
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410580/jquery-function-execute-when-all-images-are-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `.load` event fires asynchronously. JavaScript will not wait for all the images to load before proceeding with the script execution, so you need to perform the test each time an image has loaded. I've made your code a bit more readable too.

```
var len = pics.length;
var loadCounter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    $(document.createElement(img)).attr('src', pics[i]).load(function() {
        alert(pics[i] + 'is loaded');
        loadCounter++;
        if(loadCounter === len) {
            alert("all are loaded");   
        }
    });
}
```

Side note: traversing an array using `for...in` will yield nasty results. In particular, it will include all properties of `Array`, so in short, **don't do it** :) [See for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/jC8h4/)

Another thing, the load event may not fire in some browsers when the image has been cached. To avoid this problem, you can manually fire the `.load` event on each image which has its `complete` property set.

```
var len = pics.length;
var loadCounter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    $(document.createElement(img)).attr('src', pics[i]).one("load", function() {
        alert(pics[i] + 'is loaded');
        loadCounter++;
        if(loadCounter === len) {
            alert("all are loaded");   
        }
    }).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but i run your code in the console, but i got the last pic alert everytime, (3.jpg is loaded), maybe you can try   your code

Comment: @vikingmute - did you try the second example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope the `i` variable to retain the current value in the loop.

```
var j = 0; 

for( var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++ ){ 
    addHandler( i );
}

function addHandler( this_i ) {

    $(document.createElement( 'img' )).attr('src',pics[i]).load(function(){
        alert(pics[this_i]+'is loaded');
        j++;

        if(j == pics.length){
            alert('fully loaded');
        }
    });

}
```